# How to get time from Timepicker in hh:mm format in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm using silverlight toolkit **TimePicker** for allowing the user to pick a particular time. I'm using the following code to convert the time to string,

```
String Time = Timepicker.Value.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString();
```

I get the value like "03:24:20", but i just want the value in hh:mm("03:24") format. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want hh:mm format , then do the following,

```
DateTime? _datetime = Timepicker.Value;
String Time = _datetime.Value.Hour + ":" + _datetime.Value.Minute;
```

Answer (score 4):

If your time is 24hours, try:

`Timepicker.Value.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm")`,

else if your time is 12hours, try:

`Timepicker.Value.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm")`,

Answer (score 3):

To be dynamic, try this ...

```
public DateTime timeValue { get; set; }

timeValue = timePicker.Value.Value;

<TextBlock Name="timeText" Text="{Binding StringFormat=hh:mm}"/>

timeText.DataContext = timeValue;
```

Hope this helps you. And to get a date value alone in TextBlock,

```
public DateTime dateValue { get; set; }

dateValue = datePicker.Value.Value;

<TextBlock Name="dateText" Text="{Binding StringFormat=d}"/>

dateText.DataContext = dateValue;
```

Comment: Your soln works great with windows 8. Can you explain how the same can be done for windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
String Time = Timepicker.Value.ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

if you need 24-hour clock then use `HH` instead of `hh`

You better read the documentation on MSDN : [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: When i do so, i'm getting __System.FormatException__

Comment: A bit more info about the exception?

Answer (score 1):

In case of 24 hour format,the following works for me.

```
dtpStartTime.Value.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```